# Using different info messages in one Ctrl with $modal service (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, modal-dialog

I've a question to my problem. I'm using on each page an info button who's opening when you click on it. For the modal window I'm using an own defined service who's giving the values to the controller of the modal window. For each page exists an different info message and I want to use only one View for all info messages. But only the message for the corresponding page should be displayed. How can I define this?

Here is a code of Home view Info btn:

```
<button type="button" class="btn pull-right" ng-click="msgBtn()">
  click on info
</button>
```

The same code is in Person view.

How can I tell the modalCtrl that the msgBtn() was clicked on Person view and give me the message of person info?

---

Here is my solution example:

```
//First the HomeCtrl:
$scope.info = function (message) {   
   modalService.infoDia(message);
};

//HomeView:
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="info('Home')">
  Click Info
</button>

//PersonCtrl:
$scope.info = function (message) {    
   modalService.infoDia(message);
};

//PersonView:
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="info('Person')">
  Click Info
</button>

//infoDia Service:
...
return {
   infoDia: function (message) {
       return $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'info.html',
          controller: function ($scope, params) {
            $scope.message = params.message;
          },
          resolve: {
            params: function () {
              return {
                message: message;
              }
            }
          }
       });
   }
}

//ModalView:
...
<div class="modal-body">
    <p ng-if="message == 'Home'">
        This is the home information dialog.
    </p>
    <p ng-if="message == 'Person'">
        This is the person information dialog.
    </p>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Does your Home view and Person view have separate controllers?

Comment: @ankur Yes they do. Home view have the homeCtrl and person the personCtrl

Answer (score 0):

You can have a property named something like `infoMsg` in both `homeCtrl` and `personCtrl` and access it in you modal view using `{{infoMsg}}`. But this will force you to add infoMsg property to each of your controllers scope whereever you are going to use the modal. Better you can have your home and person controllers pass the message string to the modal controller through the service. This will reduce coupling and will give your code more flexibility. This is all I can tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show a message then this is pretty easily achieved. To put @ankur's answer in a form of code, it could be something like below.

Have a `Info` service, taking message as a parameter.

```
app.factory('Info', function($modal) {
  return {
    show: function(message) {
      $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'info-modal-template.html',
        controller: function($scope, params) {
          $scope.message = params.message;
        },
        resolve: {
          params: function() {
            return {
              message: message
            };
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then inject and call it from within your `HomeCtrl`.

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function(Info) { 
  var vm = this;
  vm.info = function(message) {
    Info.show(message);
  };
});
```

Where `HTML` template is simply.

```
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl as vm">
  <button type="button" 
          class="btn btn-default" 
          ng-click="vm.info('Home message')">
    Home button
  </button>
</div>
```

---

[image: imgur]
[image: imgur]

---

Answer to your new question posted as an answer.

```
// Home
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, modalService) { 
  $scope.info = function() {
    modalService.infoDia('Home');
  };
});

<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="info()">Click Info</button>

// Person
app.controller('PersonCtrl', function($scope, modalService) {
  $scope.info = function() {
    modalService.infoDia('Person');
  };
});

<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="info()">Click Info</button>

// Service
app.factory('modalService', function($modal) {
  return {
    infoDia: function(message) {
      return $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'info.html',
        controller: function($scope, params) {
          $scope.message = params.message;
        },
        resolve: {
          params: function() {
            return {
              message: message
            };
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

<div class="modal-body">
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is, that the messages are bigger than as like in your example. I can't write an bigger text in the infoDia(...) method. I think that's not a good practice. I thought I implement the text messages in the info modal window and controls that with boolean as like in my example.

Comment: Then get your messages from a resource file or similar.